# How do I set maximum number of chars in a TDBCombobox?

Tags: delphi, combobox

A TBEdit control has MaxLength property, but you don't need to do anything with it, because being a data aware control this is handled automatically.

A TDBCombobox control has no such property and max length is not handled automatically.
How should control the maximum number of chars in a TDBCombobox when Style is set to csDropDown? Ideally this should be based upon the length of the underlying field.

Comment: If it is a combobox, are you not responsible for the items that the user can choose from? Therefore you can control their length.

Comment: I have edited the question because I should have stated style is set to csDropDown (not csDropDownList). The underlying field does not control the maxlength of the DBCombobox.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a form where there are "standard" selections the user can choose, but they need to also be able to enter free-form instructions, and so I need to use `csDropDown`, so I've also noticed that `TDBComboBox` doesn't expose the `MaxLength` property that the standard `TComboBox` does, and it doesn't work just using the field size, as you've noticed.

The other problem is that if the user types in too much content, `TDBComboBox` just silently truncates it to the underlying column's size when updating it. The text still looks like it's all there until the data is posted (where the truncation occurs), but the `DBComboBox.Text` is not updated to reflect the truncation. Closing the window and then reopening it reveals the loss of data.

I work around this by using an interposer class to access the protected `MaxLength` property of the `TCustomComboBox` it descends from, to set the maximum length properly for the size of the `TStringField`:

```
type
  THackCB = class(TCustomComboBox);

procedure TEditForm.FormShow(Sender: TObject);
begin
  THackCB(TheDBComboBx).MaxLength := DataMod.MyStringField.Size;
end;
```